# How can I recreate the guitar sound of Los Lonely Boys?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar

I am at a loss as to what type guitar + amp + effects creates this particular sound.

In particular, I want to create a guitar sound similar to the lead guitar of **Los Lonely Boys**, or the closely related band, **Santana**.

Assuming I use a standard Stratocaster guitar (unless there's a different guitar I should consider), what other things should I look for to create this sound?

Comment: I have tried to set this up, but I'm currently using a Gibson Blues-hawk, which has a peculiar sound that's never quite what I'm after.  Also currently using a Roland cube amp.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To my ear, Henry Garza sounds like the phrasing of Carlos Santana with the guitar setup of Stevie Ray Vaughn.

For the SRV part, take a Strat, string it heavy, put the switch on the neck-mid position, plug into a Fender amp pushed near breakup and place a Tube Screamer in there, mostly as a boost to get the amp to grind a little when you need to. Looking at a [rig rundown](http://www.premierguitar.com/articles/Rig_Rundown_Los_Lonely_Boys_Henry_Garza), that's basically it. Add a wah, on occasion bring in a Leslie, etc, but mostly SRV's rig is well-established.

Of course, tone is in the fingers, so once you get that rig together, it'll take some time for you to get it in your hands.

Comment: This makes sense - good info here.  I'll give some time for additional answers, but this definitely helps.